# PostsController::index() was not found - CakePHP

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, wamp, autoload

I am trying to get my hands on cakephp. So I started off with the cakephp demo Blog Application. I followed the first few steps of the tutorial and when I trying to load the posts controller it says

```
Missing View
Error: The view for PostsController::index() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: T:\Project Folders\NetBeans\cakeBlog\app\View\Posts\index.ctp
```

I searched a lot about this both in stackoverflow , cakephp forum and even in googlegroups but none of the solutions seems to work from me. Most of the solutions posted are as follows:

1. Check if mod_rewrite is enabled -- Yes I have it enabled.
2. Check if you named the index.ctp as index.ctp not index.cpt , Index.ctp or any other variant. -- Yes I have placed the index as follows app/views/Posts/index.ctp (using netbeans wizard)
3. Use  tags instead of php short tags-- I am using the conventional Tag

**Development Environment**

Web Server - WAMP
I created an alias named `cakeblog` and pointed it to `cakephp_folder/app/webroot/`

***cakeblog.conf***

```
Alias /cakeblog/ "T:\Project Folders\NetBeans\cakeBlog\app\webroot/" 

<Directory "T:\Project Folders\NetBeans\cakeBlog\app\webroot/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

***app/webroot/.htaccess***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cakeblog
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also loaded the localization and the debugkit Plugin. I simply placed the exacted folders into app/plugin and added the following in bootstrap.php

***bootstrap.php***

```
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Loads a single plugin named DebugKit
CakePlugin::load('Localized');
```

***core.php***

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

I am able to launch the application and I am seeing the welcome page well and fine. I have attached an snapshot of it in startup.png

[image: startup]

Now , let me paste the code, which I simply copy pasted from the tutorial:

**app/model/post.php**

```
   <?php
    class Post extends AppModel {
        //put your code here
    }
    ?>
```

**app/controller/PostsController.php**

```
<?php

  class PostsController extends AppController {
    //put your code here
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

     public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
     public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('post', $post);
    }
}

?>
```

**app/view/Pages/Posts/index.ctp**

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/index.ctp -->

<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

Kindly check the attachment output.png for the snapshot of the output I am receiving for `http://localhost/cakeblog/posts`:

[image: output]

Comment: Good question. "still I suppose it's worth mentioning" - yes, if you are working on a tutorial, readers don't want to have to visit the tutorial to follow what you are working on. Supply everything in your post, as you have done. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change directories app/View/Pages/Posts/ to app/View/Posts/

Each controller has own dir with views files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suppose I misread the tutorial somehow. I feel a bit embarrassed now. But there is no shame in asking something simple if you are learning something new.

Answer (score 0):

View files are stored in /app/View/, in a folder named after the controller that uses the files, and named after the action it corresponds to. In your example, the view file for the Post controller’s “index()” action, would normally be found in /app/View/Posts/index.ctp.